# Unimplemented type 'builtin' in 'coerceToReal' [Rcpp]

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have just started with Rcpp. I have a simple program which takes two numerical vectors, computes their union and returns a numerical vector. The listing is pasted below (`test.cpp`).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  int n = x.size() + y.size();
  std::vector<int> v(n);
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;

  std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
  std::sort(y.begin(), y.end());

  it=std::set_union(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end(), v.begin());
  v.resize(it-v.begin());

  return wrap(v);
}


/*** R
x <- c(5,10,15,20,25)
y <- c(50,40,30,20,10)
test(x, y)
*/
```

When I try to run the program with values

```
x <- sample(20000)
y <- sample(20000)
test(x, y)
```

the function works. But when I increase number of values

```
x <- sample(1000000)
y <- sample(1000000)
test(x, y)
```

the program crashes with the output

```
Error in .Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: 0x7f1819d8af20>, x, y) : 
  unimplemented type 'builtin' in 'coerceToReal'
```

Any ideas what is happening? Thanks for any pointer or reference.

Comment: It works fine for me... What are your system specs?

Comment: @JosephWood Linuc Ubuntu box, 16 GB RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `NumericVector`s by `IntegerVector`s.
Or work with `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Seem it works now! I replaced `NumericVector`s with `IntegerVector`s.

Comment: I'm glad this works, but it is still a little confusing. Why would it work with the first case when the numbers are small as `class(sample(20000)) == class(sample(1000000))` which is `integer`.  The compiler should still complain in the first case.

Comment: I think the problem is not on the R/Rcpp part (see [this](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2011-June/002546.html)). There must be a conversion at some time. I'm not really sure.

Comment: That was some good research. Quick question can you replicate the error?  It would be interesting to run a test to see at which point the errors start creeping in.  E.g. `for (i in 20000:1000000) {test(sample(i),sample(i)); print(i)}`.

Comment: This makes my R session crash.